# how can i get a dotted line border in kinetic js?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I'm just looking for a simple dashed line border around my Kinetic.Text() object. I see here in the [documentation](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-line-tutorial/) that lines can be made to be dashes, but it's not clear how to apply this to a border for another element like Text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is very possible, just group together text and a dashed line that borders the text.  Kind of like this:

```
var group = new Kinetic.Group();
var text = new Kinetic.Text(...);
var border = new Kinetic.Line({
  dashArray: [...]
  points: [...]
});

group.add(text);
group.add(border);
```

Dash line example: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-line-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The git-hub source shows no 'dashArray' attribute on the text class, like the line class has. So I think it is not possible :/

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/shapes/Line.js

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/blob/master/src/shapes/Text.js